# Why call IQueryable methods on CompensatingCollection throws System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a query looks something like this:

```
result = (from tbl1 in dbcontext.table1
         join tbl2 in dbcontext.table2 on tbl1.field equals tbl2.field
         group tbl1 by tbl1.Id into gr
         select new
         {
             prop1 = gr.Key,
             prop2 = dbcontext.table1.Where(t => ...).Select(t => ...)
         }).ToList()
```

This query might returns a huge list of data, so my purpose is to reduce the size by just getting `prop1`, and store `prop2` as an `IQueryable` to call later when needed.

But when running, the only method I can call on `prop2` is `.ToList()`. Every other methods like `.First()` or `.Take()` throws exception:

> "This method is not supported against a materialized query result."

Debugging show that `prop2` is a type of:

> System.Linq.IQueryable<> {System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.Internal.Materialization.CompensatingCollection<>}

My question is why I cannot call `IQueryable` methods on this `CompensatingCollection`?

And what is that `CompensatingCollection` class? The only thing I found is its [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data.Entity/System/Data/Common/Internal/Materialization/CompensatingCollection.cs) but still can't understand what it is.